# The value of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate
$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \arcsin|\sin(x)|dx$$
This is my solution.Is it correct?
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\arcsin|\sin x|dx&=\int_0^\pi\arcsin\sin xdx+\int_\pi^{2\pi}-\arcsin\sin xdx\\&=\int_0^\pi xdx-\int_\pi^{2\pi}xdx\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{2}2-2\pi^2=-\pi^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: I've edited your question to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of your image, whose contents I've reproduced verbatim. (We discourage images as they're not searchable.) I haven't corrected mistakes such as the unexplained factor of $2$ when you evaluated $\int_0^\pi xdx$.

Comment: The integral from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ of $x$ is $3\pi^2/2$ not $2\pi^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most problems with an absolute value in them are made easier by getting rid of the absolute value by way of breaking the problem into cases.

$\sin x \geq 0$ on $0 \leq x \leq \pi$.  So for that part of the integral, you have $\arcsin(\sin(x))$--BUT there is another wrinkle, because of how $\arcsin x$ is defined.  In the first quadrant, the expression simplifies to $x$.  In the second quadrant, the expression simplifies to $\pi - x$.

In the third quadrant, the expression gives $\pi - x$, and in the fourth quadrant, it gives $x$.  So your integral is
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}(\pi-x) dx + \int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2} (\pi - x) dx + \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi} x dx$$

Comment: Thank you!Now I understand it.